# Square root congruence equation: solving for the modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve a system of the type

$a^2 \mod n \equiv b\\
 b^2 \mod n \equiv c\\
 c^2 \mod n \equiv d\\
 ...$

Where $n = p q$ for some primes $p$ and $q$. I know how to solve these systems when the unknown is $a$, but here the unknown is $n$. How would I go about solving such a system? I am not sure where to begin.

I tried writing it out as $a^2 - b = ipq$ for some integer $i$, and then factoring $a^2-b$, and repeating for each equation, and then intersecting the resulting solution sets. The problem is that the numbers involved are way too large for factorization to be practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ n\mid a^2\!-\!b, b^2\!-\!c, c^2\!-\!d\iff n\mid gcd(a^2\!-\!b, b^2\!-\!c, c^2\!-\!d).\:$ The solutions arise from factoring the gcd.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.